# How to get Java Doc (In Eclipse) to pop up without having to wait for it to popup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, documentation, javadoc

I'm more of an iOS developer, so I'm using the analogy of option clicking a variable to get the documentation to popup in xcode. It's quick and snappy.

In eclipse, if I want to read the documentation for a class/variable/method, I have to hold the mouse over the variable like a chump for 1-2 seconds, if I move the mouse I lose it and then it requires waiting again, and doesn't always come back, breaking every law of User experience ever written.

Just wondering if anyone knows the best way to configure eclipse with this stuff, I had a search in the preferences panel but the closest thing I found was hover, but that still didn't address the delay that I must wait when I'm just wanting to write code. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your cursor is within the item you want to view the docs for, you should be able to open/focus them by pressing F2.

Comment: Hmm ok, as I'm running it on OSX, F2 is brightness, I'll change it to something more appropriate then. But sounds like that way to go.

Comment: My mistake... I always disable the F keys' actions so I don't have to press fn ;-)